# How do I hide the soft keyboard when changing tabs?

Tags: android, android-listview

*EDIT : Seems I'm not making myself clear. What I need is a way to hide the soft keyboard whenever i replace the fragment I am in. How do I go about doing this ?*

Let me keep this simple. I have an EditText box in Tab Fragment 1.2 which obviously opens op the Soft keyboard when pressed. How do I hide this when the tab is changed? I tried the following in my onTabSelected() which doesn't seem to do anything

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

I've tried everything now. None of the suggested solutions I've located so far are helping me in any way.

Comment: add android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"> in your Activtity

Comment: This does nothing in my application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

programmatically you could use, capturing the view of the active activity on the screen of the device.

```
public final void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        View focus = getCurrentFocus();
        if (focus != null) {
            hiddenKeyboard(focus);
        }
    }
public final void onTabselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        View focus = getCurrentFocus();
        if (focus != null) {
            hiddenKeyboard(focus);
        }
    }
public final void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        View focus = getCurrentFocus();
        if (focus != null) {
            hiddenKeyboard(focus);
        }
    }

private void hiddenKeyboard(View v) {
        InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        keyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and placed the following code in my tab fragment just prior to using  the `FragmentTransaction.replace()` method to change tabs. The `onCreate` and `onCreateView` methods in each fragment are not triggered after the initial tab selection, so hiding the keyboard can be done before getting to the specific fragment's class. Using `mTabHost.getApplicationWindowToken()` rather than `editText.getWindowToken()` was a major help. Thanks to whoever found that. Sorry I lost the link.

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);             
im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mTabHost.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

.......
fm = getFragmentManager();
....

fm.beginTransaction()
    .replace(placeholder, new someFragment(), tabId)
    .commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you enable the soft keyboard

```
inputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

And this is how you close it when you switch tabs.

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

set OnPageChangeListener to viewpager in mainActivity Where you add fragments to viewPager

```
  viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(myOnPageChangeListener);




   ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener myOnPageChangeListener =
            new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                //Called when the scroll state changes.

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position,
                                       float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                //This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled,
                //either as part of a programmatically initiated smooth scroll
                //or a user initiated touch scroll.

                hideKeyboard();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                //This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
                //hide keyboard when any fragment of this class has been detached
                hideKeyboard();
            }
        };







public  void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    // check if no view has focus:
    View v = getCurrentFocus();
    if (v == null)
        return;

    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In your XML file just remove `android:focusable="true"` from everywhere.

One more thing is if you are using `<requestfocus></requestfocus>` then also remove this line.

Try it I think it should work.

Comment: I failed to explain myself properly. The problem isn't the keyboard being shown when a person focuses the EditText View. It's that the soft keyboard doesn't hide once I change to a different tab.

Comment: I think you have set android:focusable="false" this will not allow to open keyboard at all. I think you want to display keyboard only when user click on edittext so best way to remove above line from every where you are using.