# Soft keyboard remains visible after changing tabs

Tags: android

I have four tabs in my home screen and one of them takes user input.On entering data in the input tab the keyboard opens up.This keyboard remains open when i switch to other tab.Any suggestions about what i need to do ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297376/how-do-i-hide-the-soft-keyboard-when-changing-tabs

Comment: [See this - ][1]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?rq=1


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The following code is copied from [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard).

Next time, please, search the forum before posting a question:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener()
        {
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
            {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(tabHost.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: got it ! infact i posted the link that i got my answer from.Should i delete the question now ?

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you , in your `Manifest` with `Activity` `declaire` like this

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

or

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" /> for more info
```

[see Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

or

```
<activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
    </activity>
```

Comment: Tried,this but dint worked for me.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297376/how-do-i-hide-the-soft-keyboard-when-changing-tabs this is what worked for me.

Thanks for your time.