# How to close keyboard programmatically which is not owned by the current window

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have this View Pager which has a set of pages. when the user is on the first page, the keyboard pops up. While i slide through the pages, the keyboard is not closed (that is how it is implemented). now When i am on the fourth or fifth page, i explicitly try to close the keyboard using the following piece of code but it does not work. Something tells me, that it is because the keyboard was opened on a separate page (by a different fragment).

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)Context.GetSystemService(Activity.InputMethodService);
View v = ((Activity)context).CurrentFocus;
if (v == null)
    return;
imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(WindowToken, 0);
```

how is the windowtoken mapped here. I guess it is used to co-relate the view window which opened the keyboard. But don't all the pages in a pager display on the same window , essentially having the same token. If so, why doesn't it work

Comment: did you try in manifest?

Answer (score 1):

We can toggle input though. Here use this -

```
public static void toggle(Activity activity){
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm.isActive()){
        // Hide keyboard
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
    } else {
        // Show keyboard
        imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this method.In my app,this is working fine in viewpager also.

```
public void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        // Check if no view has focus:
        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    }
```

I hope its useful to you.

Comment: I had already tried this. It does not work. I don't have any view currently in focus.

Comment: @Dibzmania plz chk this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/21402632/1223291

Answer (score 0):

Implement by using the `Interface` method.

Create method in `Interface` class:

```
public interface ShowHideKeyboard(){
      void showKeyBoard();
      void hideKeyBoard();
}
```

Implement `Interface` class in your `Activity`:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompactActivity implements ShowHideKeyboard{

 @Override 
 public void hideKeyBoard() {
    View view = this.getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        view.clearFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
  }

 @Override
 public void showKeyboard() {
    ((InputMethodManager)
            (getActivity())
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
            .toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
 }

}
```

Call `showKeyBoard()` and `hideKeyBoard()` method where you want to show or hide in fragment.

```
((ShowHideKeyBoard) getActivity()).showKeyBoard();
((ShowHideKeyBoard) getActivity()).hideKeyBoard();
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. You have basically shown what I have done, just in a fancy way

Comment: You have to call hide/show method page by page whereever you need.